# Segmentation fault when running multiple threads for same vector C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

There is a shared vector with data to access by two threads. But when running below code. I got an error mentioning that **Segmentation Fault (core dump)**. Here `std::vector<json> outputOfStealthAddresses` is the shared vector. Here I'm doing is each thread need to get the first value from the vector and store it locally in the thread, then remove it from the vector (avoid double use from each thread). Here I used a **mutex** to lock the vector. Then locally stored data passed to the SQLite connection to insert the data in to the database.

**Note -** Here I'm using two SQLite connections for each thread.

Here are the two thread functions.

**Thread 1 function**

```
void runSaDataStoreThread1(){
    //creating sqlite connection
    indexMapper::indexes dbConnectionSA ("file", "sub-file","data" ,true );    //init database instance globally

    //create data table for tx details
    dbConnectionSA.createTable(saDetailTable);

    while (true){
        if(!outputOfStealthAddresses.empty()){
            std::vector<json> temp;
            mtx.lock();
                if(!outputOfStealthAddresses.empty()){
                    temp.push_back(outputOfStealthAddresses[0]);
                    outputOfStealthAddresses.erase(outputOfStealthAddresses.begin());
                }
            mtx.unlock();

            if(!temp.empty()){
                dbConnectionSA.insertSAData(temp[0]);
            }

            temp.erase(temp.begin());
        }else if(outputOfStealthAddresses.empty() && isAllBlockDone){
            break;
        }
    }
    dbConnectionSA.close();
}
```

**Thread 2 function**

```
void runSaDataStoreThread2(){
    //creating sqlite connection
    indexMapper::indexes dbConnectionSA1 ("file", "sub-file","data-2" ,true );    //init database instance globally

    //create data table for tx details
    dbConnectionSA1.createTable(saDetailTable);

    while (true){
        if(!outputOfStealthAddresses.empty()){
            std::vector<json> temp2;

            mtx.lock();
            if(!outputOfStealthAddresses.empty()){
                temp2.push_back(outputOfStealthAddresses[0]);
                outputOfStealthAddresses.erase(outputOfStealthAddresses.begin());
            }
            mtx.unlock();

            if(!temp2.empty()){
                dbConnectionSA1.insertSAData(temp2[0]);
            }

            temp2.erase(temp2.begin());
        }else if(outputOfStealthAddresses.empty() && isAllBlockDone){
            break;
        }
    }
    dbConnectionSA1.close();
}
```

**main function**

```
int main(){
  auto thread11 = std::thread(parse::runSaDataStoreThread1);
  auto thread16 = std::thread(parse::runSaDataStoreThread2);

  thread11.join();
  thread16.join();
}
```

Comment: Read up on *synchronization*.

Comment: I also see zero point in using vectors `temp` and `temp2` respectively. They never contain more than a single element of data. Furthermore, this code is all but identical in both threads, save for the arguments passed to the db connections. You could use parameters to those threads, provided at construction, and eliminate half your code. The rampant use of globals certainly isn't doing this much help either. As mentioned elsewhere, protection of your data predicates is important, and it isn't being done here. I can only imagine what the thread pushing data into the vector does.

Comment: Thanks for the replying.  @WhozCraig can you please point out the place of the doubt in the code?

Comment: I doubt the *entire* code. I don't know what the actual *purpose* of this even is. It *looks* like you're trying to toggle back and forth between two threads, each reading the next item from the vector. Whether that is the case, and whether it is is left as a mystery. If you stop thinking of `outputOfStealthAddresses` as a vector and start thinking of it as a *queue* it may be more sensible, but I don't know if that is an accurate depiction. This has all the makings of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to protect all calls to the vector methods with the mutex. Specifically, the `empty()` calls.

Comment: can you please explain this?

Comment: @SajithaLiyanage, A thread calling `outputOfStealthAddresses.empty()` could see the internals of the vector object in an inconsistent state if the other thread happens to be half-way through the `erase(...)` call.  Anything (e.g., a Segmentation Fault) could happen at that point.

Comment: @YSC ,james Thanks. I solved it after adding mutex to all the process. Including the empty() call. :)

Answer (score 0):

as for your concrete problem:

you need to use a mutex to lock all operations on your vector.

as for the problem you actually seem to try to solve:
i assume you want to speed up your sqlite insertions by parallelizing them?
if so: this will not solve your performance problem. what you should do is:
do your inserts as a single transaction.